# Generate a list of url's from terminal using a list from a text file?

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a list of addresses in a text file that I need to get be able to hyperlink to on a project I'm working on. How do I generate a list of these url's needed for hyperlink using the addresses in the text file?

list of addresses in text file:

```
4015 FOREST HILL CIR 
4019 FOREST HILL CIR
6500 HARTMAN RD
4423 FOREST HILL CIR 
4701 FOREST HILL CIR 
4722 SE LOOP 820 
4724 SE LOOP 820 
4725 FOREST HILL CIR 
4800 SE LOOP 820 
5100 SE LOOP 820 
5120 SE LOOP 820 
5140 SE LOOP 820

URL:
```

> msc.fema.gov/portal/search?AddressQuery=**4423%20FOREST%20HILL%20CIRCLE%20FORT%20WORTH%2C%20TX%20**#searchresultsanchor

the bolded portion above `(4423%20FOREST%20HILL%20CIRCLE%20FORT%20WORTH%2C%20TX%20)` is the part I need want to automatically loop through and replace with another address from the list and the new url to the list

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should also post here some code that you have attempted.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure I understand the problem, for each line in the file, you want to replace any spaces with %20 and then insert the result into the rest of the URL (which is static) ?
There are probably many way to do this (and I don't consider myself a BASH expert), but working from the back :

```
echo "${BaseURL1}${URLVar}${BaseURL2}"
```

should do it. Where earlier in your script you have :

```
BaseURL1='https://msc.fema.gov/portal/search?AddressQuery='
baseURL2='#searchresultsanchor'
```

I'd do it this way because you can then use single quotes round the static bit and avoid the need for escaping all the special characters, but then double quotes later when you combine them so as to evaluate the variables.

I'd probably use sed to change the spaces :

```
sed -e 's/ /%20/'
```

And wrap the whole lot in a while loop :

```
while read InputVar < ${InputFile}
do
  URLVar=`echo "${InputVar}" | sed -e s/ /%20/`
  echo "${BaseURL1}${URLVar}${BaseURL2}"
done
```

This may possibly have some errors and be incomplete, but it should get you on the right track.
If you are unfamiliar with them, backticks in bash (and other shells) mean "evaluate what's inside them and execute the result" - so in this case sends the string read from the input to stdin of sed, and sets the value of URLVar to the output of sed's stdout.